# php:src path in included files not rendering properly

Tags: php

I have created a php file that consists path say rootdir/level1/level2/sample.jpg  Now i want to include this file from any where i.e., from any level. how to do it.  So that i can get image in any level of path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/level1/level2/sample.jpg">
```